# How to add objects to a local household database?

Tags: ros, household-objects-database, cturtle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to add objects to the household database downloaded from willow garage.
However, i don't know how to add the objects to the database. The API documentation of household_objects_database mention a PLYModelLoader class, but i'm unable to find it in my ROS files.
My ROS version is cturtle 1.2.4 .

Any idea how to do this ?

Best regards,

Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9619/how-to-add-objects-to-a-local-household-database-?/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-04-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should update to atleast Diamondback, and checkout the source file https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/object_manipulation/trunk/household_objects_database/src/mesh_loader.cpp

Try using this as a template to move forward.

---

Originally posted by [ethanrublee](https://answers.ros.org/users/200/ethanrublee/) with karma: 225 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-06-20**:
Thanks for the answer, I will try upgrading to diamondback first and then we will see.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After upgrading to diamondback, also take a look at the insert_model.cpp node in the household_objects_database package. It is somewhat crude and not well parameterized, but should have all the info needed.

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-06-20**:
Okay, I will try this. Thanks for the reply.

**Comment by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) on 2012-04-13**:
As a note, insert_model will try to copy the geometry file to a location specified in the database itself, by the MODEL_ROOT entry in the "variables" table. Change that to point to somewhere in your filesystem before trying insert_model.